# What element is generating a large margin in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When viewing [my site](http://www.asstataukaipidiotas.lt) in chrome there is a large margin at the bottom at the page. What element is generating this?

Actually I found out the problem by cutting down the code in pieces.

Comment: ctrl shift i is your friend in chrome

Comment: i think you are using wordpress right ? try disable and enable plugins..

Comment: Try to make your question useful to future readers by including relevant source code and/or a test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you validate your code. ( http://validator.w3.org ).  There's a lot of invalid markup and incorrectly nested tags, any one of which could cause layout problems.

Comment: I cannot even check it. I get the error - Sorry! This document can not be checked.

Comment: The reason for “This document can not be checked” is that it contains character-level data errors, i.e. bytes (bit patterns) that do not constitute characters in the declared encoding. If you manually set the encoding e.g. to windows-1252 in the validator’s user interface (dropdown “Encoding”), you’ll get started with fixing the errors. The reason for the character-level data error is probably cut and paste of text that was in another encoding.